# Can not send arabic Characters in URL In android

Tags: java, android, arabic

How do I send Arabic Characters in the URL? I have tried :

```
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");
```

to encode Data in arabic and send it over the server. but at the receiver's end it shows up as ?????

Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: what character you using give a sample character

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

at top of your php file insted of using in android.

Comment: I am not using PHP , i am making URL connection through Java using HTtpUrLConnection. Thus , i want native android  code support. I have also tried the above code.